# Serializing objects containing django querysets

Tags: python, django, json

Django provides tools to serialize querysets (django.core.serializers), but what about serializing querysets living inside other objects (like dictionaries)?

I want to serialize the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = { 'alfa': queryset1, 'beta': queryset2, }
```

I decided to do this using **simplejson** (comes with django).
I extended **simplejson.JSONEncoder** the following way:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core import serializers

class HandleQuerySets(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
     """ simplejson.JSONEncoder extension: handle querysets """
     def default(self, obj):
         if isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
             return serializers.serialize("json", obj, ensure_ascii=False)

         return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Then I do: `simplejson.dumps( dictionary, cls=HandleQuerySets)`, but the returned dicionary looks like this:

```
{ "alfa": "[{\"pk\": 1, \"model\": \"someapp.somemodel\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"alfa\"}}]",
  "beta": "[{\"pk\": 1, \"model\": \"someapp.somemodel\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"alfa\"}}]" }
```

Django-generated JSON is inserted to the dictionary as string, not JSON. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core import serializers
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class HandleQuerySets(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
     """ simplejson.JSONEncoder extension: handle querysets """
     def default(self, obj):
         if isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
             return serializers.serialize("python", obj, ensure_ascii=False)
         return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Because `serializers.serialize("json", [...])` returns a string ; if you ask for the `python` serializer, you get a dictionnary, and json encodes whatever is returned by your encoder's `default` method. Look at the [json documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) for details.

You will have to handle more types in your encoder class (such as datetime objects), but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! I made a slight modification to handle datetime objects, etc.  `from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder` and then you can extend DjangoJSONEncoder instead of simplejson.JSONEncoder.  Then, just change the last line in HandleQuerySets to `return DjangoJSONEncoder.default(self, obj)`