# Django, passing JSON to frontend, 'str' doesn't have 'iteritems'

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I'm creating json data this way:

```
def get_all_from_database():
    urls = Url.objects.all()
    ips = Ip.objects.all()
    urls_json = serializers.serialize('json', urls)
    ips_json = serializers.serialize('json', ips)
    return urls_json, ips_json
```

and I try to pass it to frontend using ajax:

```
@csrf_exempt
def send_results(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        address = request.POST.get('url')
    urls, ips = get_all_from_database()
    return HttpResponse(urls, ips)
```

js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/link_finder/send_results/",
    data: {
        url : web_page,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Please report this error: "+errorThrown+xhr.status+xhr.responseText);
    }
```

And I get this error:

```
INTERNAL SERVER ERROR500AttributeError at /link_finder/send_results/
'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Why? And what should I change?

Comment: What is the full traceback produced in your logs?

Comment: have you tried using json.dumps() ?

Comment: paste the log from your terminal

Comment: I dont get any log in terminal, just "POST /link_finder/send_results/ HTTP/1.1" 500 11640

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponse` takes only **one** body argument, you are passing in two.

Don't create two JSON strings, build one, using [a custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093840/serializing-objects-containing-django-querysets) to handle multiple querysets:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder 
from django.core import serializers
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet


def get_all_from_database():
    urls = Url.objects.all()
    ips = Ip.objects.all()
    return urls, ips

class HandleQuerySets(DjangoJSONEncoder):
     """ JSONEncoder extension: handle querysets """
     def default(self, obj):
         if isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
             return serializers.serialize("python", obj, ensure_ascii=False)
         return super(HandleQuerySets, self).default(obj)

@csrf_exempt
def send_results(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        address = request.POST.get('url')
    urls, ips = get_all_from_database()
    data = HandleQuerySets().encode({'urls': urls, 'ips': ips})
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

I've also set the correct Content-Type header for you.

Comment: I tried this, but it raises errror: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: @user3156971: right, indeed, the serializer only can handle query sets. Corrected by using a custom encoder instead.